# How to get the content of the selected button

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I am looking for a JavaScript equivalent

```
document.getElementById("Button").innerHTML
```

in C # WPF.

I need to get button content by x:Name

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the code behind (e.g. `myView.xaml.cs`) of your xaml (e.g. `myView.xaml`) file.

Something like this

```
string text = Button1.Content.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

If the button is an element on the page and has the name "myButton" then you can access its content from within the parent class as `myButton.Content`.

Comment: I do not want the inscription from the button, I want to get elements that can be found in it, e.g. rectangle

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you're looking for:

```
string buttonContent = ((Button)FindName("Button1"))?.Content.ToString();
```